# CS1061 error in orchard captcha Modules

Tags: orchardcms

I'm getting error CS1061  in orchard  captcha Modules([MainBit.Captcha](https://github.com/MainBit/MainBit.Captcha))

```
@model MainBit.Captcha.ViewModel.CaptchaViewModel
<fieldset>
    <label class="required">
        @T("Type captcha")<br />
        <img src="@(Model.Src)"/>
    </label>
    <input id="@(Model.ValueFieldName)" name="@(Model.ValueFieldName)" required="required" type="text" value="">
    <input id="@(Model.GuidFieldName)" name="@(Model.GuidFieldName)" type="hidden" value="@(Model.Guid)">
    @*@Html.TextBox(Model.ValueFieldName, "", new { required = "required" })
    @Html.Hidden(Model.GuidFieldName, Model.Guid)*@
</fieldset>


<input id="@(Model.ValueFieldName)" name="@(Model.ValueFieldName)" required="required" type="text" value="">
<input id="@(Model.GuidFieldName)" name="@(Model.GuidFieldName)" type="hidden" value="@(Model.Guid)">
```

The  2 lines  error:

> 1.CS1061 “CaptchaViewModel” does not contain “GuidFieldName” definition for and no “GuidFieldName”extension method accepting a first“CaptchaViewModel” argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2.CS1061 “CaptchaViewModel” does not contain “ValueFieldName” definition for and no “ValueFieldName”extension method accepting a first“CaptchaViewModel” argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I use vs2015 and Orchard 1.9.3.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like an issue of the module, but you already filed an issue